# How to upload a file to S3 bucket with axios using React and a presigned using aws-sdk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, axios

After seeing so many posts in regards with uploading files to S3 for me seem to not working any method. I've ended up with this method which seem to work in couple of posts and I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

The `presignedUrl` I get it using the `aws-sdk` on node server and everything is fine with that but when it comes to upload the actual file using the following method it return a protocol error;

Get the file and make a request to sign it

```
let file = target.files[0];
    // Split the filename to get the name and type
    let fileParts = target.files[0].name.split('.');
    let fileName = formatFilename(fileParts[0]);
    let fileType = fileParts[1];

    const { signedRequest } = await axios.post('/upload', { fileName, fileType })
```

Create a `FormData`

```
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('image', file)
    bodyFormData.append('name', fileName)
```

Then I will upload the file

```
const uploadImageRequest = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: signedRequest,
        body: bodyFormData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }

    axios(uploadImageRequest)
        .then(result => {
            console.log("Response from s3", result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("ERROR ", error);
        })
```

Finally it returns the following error

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at isURLSameOrigin.js:57
    at xhr.js:109
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.exports (xhr.js:12)
    at e.exports (dispatchRequest.js:50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url (signedRequest) you are using in axios is not undefined

Comment: I have the signed url from backend as I said. The issue is when it comes to upload the file

Comment: Here: `const { signedRequest } = await axios.post('/upload', { fileName, fileType })`

Comment: most probably the url you are using with axios is undefined

Comment: are you sure signedRequest is not undefined?

Comment: You are right. Stupid me.  The response is `data.data.signedRequest` not `signedRequest`

Comment: You are not stupid we make mistakes like this all the time ;)